# DotNetNuke : How to do single sing-on to multiple portals

Tags: cookies, subdomain, dotnetnuke, portal

I have a Dotnetnuke environment with multiple portals running at different subdomains (serviceA.company.com, serviceB.company.com). I can allow users the access to each portal by adding rows to UserPortals table, but since DNN uses full domain name in the auth cookie, the users need to log separately to each portal.

I'd like to have the system working so, that you only need to log in once on some of the portals, and wouldn't have to log in on the others. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by changing the web.config.

It's been a while since I did this, but I think you need to change the following

`<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" domain="" />`
to
`<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" domain="*.company.com" />`

I might be off on the setting, but there is a way to do this in the web.config. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
That would propably be the way to go, but in this scenario we have multiple portals and some of them have totally different domains. I'm now considering my own cookie handling, that would override/rewrite DNN's cookies.

Comment: I will mark this as an answer, as this would work well when you only have portals in the same domain.

Comment: Yes this would be limited to domains at this point due to the way browsers handled cookies.